# how to make view controller similar like fragment in android for ios

Tags: ios, swift3, ui-design

I am very new in iOS development and wanna make design similar to my Android app.
below is the Image of Android App that I wanna replicate in iOS.
any help, source or reference would be appreciated.

Description:

Screen 1 : Screen one is main page with filter list on top (blue patch)

Screen 2 : By tapping change filter whole screen slides down and behind screen get visible (which holds filter)

Screen 3 : Highlighted part changes with other page on basis of menu selection.

sorry for bad English, but i hope you guys understand.

Thank you in advance

[image]

Comment: You can have two viewcontrollers for filter screen and listing screen. Present/push filter viewcontroller on tapping filter and using delegate method get the filter params on the listing viewcontroller and populate data accordingly.

Comment: You can easily do this in a single view controller. You can animate constraints to have the white part slide down and reveal the filter settings that were hidden behind it

Comment: @Paulw11 Exactly what I want, but very confused how to do? as I also have to show selected filter in horizontal list (Dark blue patch). If you have any reference then please share

Comment: Unfortunately your question is pretty broad. You should study autolayout. You can then have an outlet to the constraint thatbcontrols the top of your filter list and animate it as required

Answer (score 0):

You can have two view controller screen(One Main Screen and another for Filter). There is no concept of fragments. What I prefer I used to have xib for reusable view and storyboard for creating activity like your Android. Code for the same will be done in ViewController.

Comment: any reference or code snippet ? so I'll look and understand and work according to my need